# Archive software releases versioned by folder into Git

Tags: git, github

I have some software containing around 70 releases over the past decade and no version control software was used.  Each release is a separate folder.  Is there an easy way to import all the source code into Git tagged by release?  There are no branches.  Just one long line of releases and each folder is the version number.  My primary intention is to use Git for archiving.  I doubt I will ever want to branch a very old release.  I would like to use Github for backup / redundancy benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an empty repo. Unpack the snapshots, one at a time or all at once does not matter, into scratch space, and `git add` and `git commit` from the unpacked trees. Ignoring the steps to actually do the per-release unpacking, the git commands to import them is:

```
git init history_xyz; cd $_
git --work-tree=/path/to/oldest/release add .
git commit -m v0.1
git --work-tree=/path/to/next/oldest add .
git commit -m v1.0
```

and so forth.

When you're done with the launder/rinse/repeat cycle put them in the dryer and pack them away nicely:

```
git repack -ad
```